# readstream display dataframe does nto work

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have loaded the delta bronze table using autoloader in databricks.

now I want to read this table and display it to see. But Im not I get the error when `display(df)` runs.

my code:

```
df= spark.readStream.format("delta") \
  .option("readChangeFeed", "true") \
  .table("mdp_prd.bronze.nrq_customerassetproperty_autoloader_nodups")
```

Error:

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DisplayHelper.getStreamName. Trace:
py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Method public static java.lang.String com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DisplayHelper.getStreamName() is not whitelisted on class class com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.DisplayHelper
at

```
py4j.security.WhitelistingPy4JSecurityManager.checkCall(WhitelistingPy4JSecurityManager.java:473)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:305)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:195)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the cluster in databricks from shared to single user and it worked